# Disable automatic updates in AcdSee Pro 5

Tags: windows, updates

I cannot find how to disable ACDSee Pro 5 automatic updates. There is no such option in application settings.

The annoying notification comes up after every reboot.

[image]

And the annoying window comes up if I click the notification icon. There is no popup-menu.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the below folder

```
C:\Program Files\ACD Systems\ACDSee Pro\5.0
```

then delete the `ACDSeeProInTouch2.exe` file.

Or:

- Run `msconfig`
- Then go to the *Startup* tab
- Disable the `C:\Program Files\ACD Systems\ACDSee Pro\5.0\ACDSeeProInTouch2.exe`
- Click *Apply* and then restart

Answer (score 1):

1. After installation, go to Firewall and disable ACDsee.exe in inbound-outbound rule.
2. Go to file location, delete "acdIDInTouch2".exe
3. Go to registry key in window search type regedit and go to
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ACD Systems\acdIDInTouch2\20
4. Edit CheckTime and ReminderTime, put ahead date so far
   (to avoid update very soon).
5. Done !!!

It's working in all version of ACDsee...